# How to build template project for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I work with Android Studio. I have to create many projects alway with three modules:

- app (application)
- library (library)
- wallpaper (application)

I know that is possibile to use ADT to build Activity Templates, etc. 
I found some tutorial like [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/502) and [this](http://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-create-custom-android-code-templates/), but they talk about activity template, no project with modules template.

Are there good tutorial around to create Project template for Android Studio directly with the structure i need?

Which IDE can i use to manage template like a project (content assistant, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but it is nothing different than building an Activity Template.

Have a look in the folder `android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities`. And more specifically in the `MasterDetailFlow` template. You see that you can add an arbitrary amount of activities, resources and layouts in your template. So the templates are not limiting you from creating a whole project as a template project.

In each of the files you can use the variables defined in the `globals.xml.ftl`.