# Is it possible to create a template project for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to create a complete Template project for Android Studio i.e. `AndroidManifest.xml` `build.gradle` should also be a template.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758751/how-to-build-template-project-for-android-studio) question and I know that its possible to create a template for group of files and then later import them in an existing project, however, this is not what I want to achieve. My final objective goal is to generate whole Android Studio project via command line. For starters though, I want to be able to import that template project in android studio and configure any parameters while importing.

Is it even possible? if yes then any pointers?

Comment: Yeoman already has Android generators

Comment: Thanks! It seems wonderful.. I did not know about it. I exactly want to create something like this but tailored to my use case.